# Handling form state with NGRX / @Effects

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a form and on submit I dispatch an action which is caught by an effect. The effect then does the http call. I'm wondering how off the back of this action completing / failing I would do the following:

- show a success message once the action completes
- reset all the fields ready for when the form is next used
- show an error off the back of the action failing

I understand I could re-dispatch an action to populate the store with several flags `success`, `error` etc. However, resetting the form will probably be done by calling a function. Would it be acceptable to subscribe to the store and calling the relevant `reset` function in the child? It's almost as if I'd like components to be able to listen to actions just like effects can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your effect-rest does not affect the store, but only should display a notification - then there are two ways I'd say:

**1) Inject `Actions` in your component as you suggested yourself:**

```
class SomeComponent {
    constructor(actions: Actions) {
        actions.ofType(SOME_EVENT)
            .do(myThing)
            .takeUntil(componentIsDestroyed)
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

---

**2) Or don't go the effects- and actions-way at all and just call a simple service-method:**

```
class SomeComponent {
    constructor(myService: CoolService) {
    }

    onClick(): void {
        mySevice.makeRequest()
            .do(myThing)
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```